# How to access Mainactivity component from non Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-broadcast

I just want to update the data from non activity class to Mainactivty layout component. In my below scenario am always getting nullpointer exception when I try to access Mainactivity component(settext)

**My MainActivty code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

(For the above class I have layout which include some textview and EditText component)

**My non activity class** (JFYI, when I get any new sms the below class will be triggered)

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

String Orgi_Phonenumber;
String Orgi_MessageText;
Activity activity;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.i("MyMessage", "start reading message information");
        Object[] smsobject = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        for (int i = 0; i < smsobject.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage CurrentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsobject[i]);
            Orgi_Phonenumber += CurrentMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
            Orgi_MessageText += CurrentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
        }

    }
    Log.i("MyMessage","start updating message info " );
    changemessage();
}
public void changemessage()
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.EtextPhone);
    tv.setText(Orgi_Phonenumber);
}
}
```

From the above non activty class(IncomingSms ) ,while am calling the mainactivty layout component

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.EtextPhone);
```

am getting nullpointer exception. Please help out I just know only basics on android

Comment: where you set the value of the class variable activity? for example you can set the value in somewhere like constructor. in the shared code you have not set the value for this variable, so it make sense that it be null.

Comment: This is like small sms app. When I receiving sms I just getting those User's Phone number(variable Orgi_Phonenumber) and User texted information from the incomingsms class.

Comment: For your question to be more specific I am getting value from code  SmsMessage CurrentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsobject[i])

Comment: I understand what you want from the app but when you have an class variable you must set the value for it and then use it. some where that you should set the value for the 'activity' variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just tried using class variable Activity activity to access mainactivity component, I know code is wrong plz tell me how to access the mainactivity component (settext) from non activty class...

Comment: register the receiver in your activity `onReceive()` will be implemented there, so you can access textviews and edittexts...